# Is there any free WPF visualizer for VS2010

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, visualizer, snoop

Is there any free wpf visualizer available, a quick google search show tool name "**mole**" and "**snoop**", 
 any one have experience with them, are they really helpfull?

Comment: Did you have a look at the build-in Visualizer? Just set a break-point and click the magnifier in the watch window of the Element you want to inspect.

Comment: yes first i use default visualizer but unable to view the dynamically genrated control, am i missing any thing here?.

Comment: Set the breakpoint on a line that is hit AFTER the control has been created and added to the visual tree.

Comment: adding button inside grid ,even after Grid.Children.Add(btn)  unable to view button in visualizer, but other columns are visible

Comment: Has there been a layout pass? Try putting the break point somewhat further ahead in time.

Comment: you should read up on difference between logical tree and visual tree in wpf. adding something via Children.Add() does not cause the visual to be created immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mole and snoop are both valuable tools. Mole more for in-depth debugging and debug visualization and snoop to simply look at your visual tree. Are you looking for anything specific?

Comment: i want to visualize control those getting genrated dynamically

Comment: with both snoop and mole you can inspect a running application.